# .JAR + Android?

Tags: android, jar

I just purchased an Archos 5 and I'm wondering if it is possible to put a .JAR file on it and use it as an application. I read somewhere that it is possible but saw somewhere else that it wasn't. If it is possible, is there anything I have to do differently? Or do I just run it like I would on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

Android devices run Android applications, not ordinary Java applications, and the ARCHOS 5 is no exception. While Android applications are written in Java, an ordinary Java desktop application uses a different GUI framework than Android offers.

Comment: +1 Android is not java, although applications are developed in Java, bytecode is then compiled so that is can run on the dalvik vm.  You can not currently run a java application on Android.

Comment: Seeing +1 in the text of a comment yet no upvotes for the answer has to be the most bizarre thing I've seen on SO yet!

Comment: my bad, I forgot to do that, nice catch

Answer (score 0):

As said by CommonsWare, although Android apps are written in Java you can't actually run Java code(s) on Android devices sinces Android actually has the Dalvick Virtual Machine as compared to the Java Virtual Machine (which runs the Java Bytecode)

If you still plan to use the logic of your jar file and run it on your device, you may reference it in an android app and use the feature(s) from it.

But be awared, that this mostly depends on what your jar file actually does and how it is packed. You may need to, otherwise, repack it to suit if for using in it Android apps.

Bottom line is, however, you can't run the jar files directly on the device!